# Stop breaking words in CSS

Tags: html, css, format

I want to stop my block from breaking words (the block contains just some sentences without abnormally long words), so I added the `word-break: keep-all` but it doesn't work - it still breaks in the middle of words. How can I fix it?

```
.example {
    float: left;
    width: 420px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: keep-all;
}


<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <x:message id="id" style="display: block" styleClass="example"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that CSS doesn't break words unless you specify `word-break: break-word;` or `word-break: break-all;` Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aj9szrpr/1/ Are there some other styles effecting the element?

Answer (score 1):

In Css :

```
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
-ms-hyphens: none;
hyphens: none;
```

Should do the job :)

Refere : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Comment: This worked for me, where all the word-break and word-wrap did not.  Any no one else seemed to mentioned this property.  Why?  am I missing something and this is a bad practice?